# Spring boot application executes without any error but not creating any tables in the backend

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have created a spring boot and RestAPI application project. Everything runs and executes but it is not creating any table in the backend (MySQL). It is not showing any error in the console too. I am new to spring boot and APIs.

Below is the code in my:

**application.properties :**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EjikeDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&&autoReconnect=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=MacRoot31
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true


spring.jpa.show-sql=true


spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

########### SMTP Email Properties ###################
spring.mail.host=smtp.mailtrap.io
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=f26e44090838e5
spring.mail.password=b2a684f17dbfc2
spring.mail.protocol=smtp


############ JWT Properties #####################
jwt.expiration.time=90000
```

and

**User.java :**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.time.Instant;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "MarketplaceUser")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userid;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is required")
    private String userName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Email is required")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
    private String password;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String country;
    private String provinceState;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    @NotBlank(message = "Postcode is required")
    private String postalCode;
    private String roles;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Product> product;
    private Instant created;
    private boolean enabled;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    

}
```

I tried adding the **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update**
and
**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create** both
aswell as

createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&&autoReconnect=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false to my application.properties file.

But nothing changed. And the main issue being there's no error displayed in the console.

[This is the project structure. If in case there's any error in this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRPiz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had same issue that spring wasn't creating mysql tables, but this line in application.properties fixed it
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create`

Comment: Hey shyga, I have already tried adding that to my application.properties but no luck. I also have the show-sql=true too but cant see any SQL commands too

Answer (score 0):

Is your entity class in the same package or a relative one where you have the main spring class (the one you add the `@EnableAutoConfiguration`)? If not, spring probably won't find it. And this is leading to your program being executed but nothing being created in DB.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue until I moved the User.java file inside the same package of my main Spring Boot application class.